# Ignore errors for included yaml file

Tags: yaml, ansible

I have the following YAML file that makes a reference to a another yaml file whose errors I want to ignore.

```
---
- hosts: personal
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: command1
      command: "nodanger command1"
      register: command1
      ignore_errors: yes
    - debug: var=command1.stdout_lines

-include: additional.yml
   ignore_errors: yes
```

When I run the above playbook I get the following error

```
ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, command.yml
Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 11, column 1


-include: additional.yml
```

How do I go about ignoring the errors for an included yml file?

Answer (score 4):

Syntax error in in your yaml file. Fixed it.

```
- include: additional.yml
  ignore_errors: yes
```

Comment: Fixing that produces the following error due to the colon in ignore_errors:

Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 12, column 17
- include: irstatus.yml
   ignore_errors: yes

Comment: @Zee can you update your post with what you tried. I have no issues running it.